# What factors could have caused the ceramic capacitors on this board to crack?

Tags: capacitor, component-failure, failure-analysis

While examining an old VGA card for faults under a microscope I found that all of the ceramic capacitors had cracked. The card is circa 1991 so it does have some age on it. But I wouldn't expect solid state capacitors to crack by themselves due to age.

NASA released [a report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20190001592) in 2019 about the "cracking problem" with low voltage capacitors but the ones on this board are 50V and have axial leads which would have mitigated a number of additional failure points mentioned in this report.

The rated 50V of these capacitors is also well above anything that should have come across the ISA bus connector. I can only guess that this might be a result of a surge or other spike from the motherboard or power supply but I'm unfamiliar with this kind if failure.

Is this kind of failure common in this era of electronics? Does age play a factor in the failure or these kind of solid state capacitors? Is this failure type illustrative of a power surge or environmental factor?

There are 20 ceramic capacitors on this board, all rated at 50V and every one of them is cracked: some severely but there is no evidence of charring and the glass capsules are all intact.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing cracks in those pics. Could you describe what you're referring to or point them out in the pics?

Comment: Remove a suspect device and test it.

Comment: A *surge or other spike* would impact more components than the capacitors.  Board looks pristine so an assumption that *all* capacitors are bad seem not realistic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no cracks. Probably you think the boundary surface of the resin within the casing is a crack. It's just the boundary between air and resin and it looked like that already 30 years ago.

You could desolder / clip any of the capacitors and test it. Probably it'd be be fine.

Comment: I was so confident that they were cracked but I've examined them again and I'm sure that it was just an illusion. I didn't know they were filled with a resin or anything else that would have disoriented what I was seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not cracks. It's an optical illusion as the inside of glass tube is not completely fillex with epoxy, there is air bubbles and epoxy and what looks like a crack is a boundary of air and epoxy.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible factors might affect the mechanical stability. The most obvious is temperatures changes, with the temperatures cycling up and down for years. Another might be if the ceramic has piezoelectric characteristics, so as it sees an AC voltage it vibrates.

Comment: One might expect most normal failures to occur in only one or possibly a very limited quantity before rendering the card inoperable (I can only guess). It's strange in this case that it's every single one. It's very strange. There is no display when the board is powered on and the computer refuses to boot entirely; something it can do just fine with no video card at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that the through hole soldering came disconnected from the pcb. I would flip it over an check all the c's for continuity. Most the time, a separation or a suspect connection will develop around the edges of the board. Also, if it's legacy equipment, some motherboards may not even recognize it at boot up. You may have to go into your bios settings to install.